# dynamic data frame in loop and filtering in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am trying to use loop to read files and at the same time clean some records based on the eventdate.

The loop looks like this

```
for(i in 1:N) {              # Head of for-loop for reading files
  assign(paste0("otherpain_",i),value =  readRDS(file_list[i])) # Body of for-loop
  assign(paste0("otherpain",i,"_clean"),value =  subset((as.name(paste0("otherpain_",i))), eventdate >= 
                                                          "2009-01-01"&
                                                          eventdate <=
                                                          "2020-12-31"))
  data_path <- paste0("./2_data_files/","otherpain_",as.character(i),"_clean.rds")
  saveRDS(paste0("otherpain",i,"_clean"), file = data_path)
  }
```

when I run it I get this error

```
Error in subset.default((as.name(paste0("otherpain_", i))), eventdate >= :
object 'eventdate' not found
```

but all dataframes contain eventdate filed.

Does anybody have solutions?

Comment: In your second line try `get` instead of `as.name` and the parantheses don't seem to be correct: `assign(paste0("otherpain",i,"_clean"), value = subset(get(paste0("otherpain_", i)),  eventdate >= "2009-01-01" & eventdate <= "2020-12-31"))`.

Comment: Instead of using a `for` loop it probably would be better to do everything inside a function and use this function with `lapply` or `purrr::map`. This would avoid creating many objects in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you could write a function and loop over that function with `lapply` or event better `purrr::walk`. I assume `file_list` and `N` exist already.

```r
read_clean_save_data <- function(i) {
  x <- readRDS(file_list[i]))
  x_clean <- subset(x, eventdate >= "2009-01-01" & eventdate <= "2020-12-31"))
  data_path <- paste0("./2_data_files/","otherpain_",as.character(i),"_clean.rds")
  saveRDS(x_clean, file = data_path)
} 

lapply(seq_len(N), read_clean_save_data)
```

Alternatively use `purrr::walk`:

```r
purrr::walk(seq_len(N), read_clean_save_data)
```